# Largest volume of an open box.

Tags: calculus

I need a quick check on this problem. Am I doing this right?

> ? If 1200 $cm^2$ of material is available to make a box with a square base and an open top, find the largest possible volume of the box.

So I setup my problem like this:

$$ x^2 + 4xh = 1200 = P$$

$$x^2 \cdot h = V$$

So I am now trying to express h in terms of x so I can get the volume equation down to 1 variable and then find the derivative of the volume equation. Is this approach right?

$$4xh = 1200 - x^2$$

$$\frac{1200 - x^2}{4x} = h$$

So,

$$ x^2 \cdot \frac{1200 - x^2}{4x} = V$$

$$ = \frac{x \cdot (1200 - x^2)}{4} = V$$

$$\frac{1}{4} ( \frac{d}{dx} \cdot ( x ( 1200 - x^2))) = V'$$

$$ = \frac{-2x^2 + 1200 - x^2}{4}$$
$$ = 300 - \frac{3x^2}{4}$$

$$V' = 0 $$ when x = 20

So max volume is $20 \cdot h$  and $h = \frac{1200-x^2}{4x} = 10$

So max volume = 300

Is this right?

Comment: $300$ seems too small for being the largest volume (in $cm^3$). The volume of the cube box is $\sqrt{240}^3 = 960\sqrt{15} \approx 3718$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max vol is $x^2h$ not $xh$, hence $20^2\cdot 10=4000$, not $20\cdot 10$ (which is, by the way, 200, not 300).

Answer (score 1):

*Oh, no, I forgot how to use derivatives!* Maybe I can solve this anyway, let's see.
$$ 1200=x^2+4xh=x^2+2xh+2xh\stackrel{\text{AM-GM}}{\geq} 3\sqrt[3]{x^2\cdot 2xh\cdot 2xh} =3\cdot4^{1/3} V^{2/3}$$
so $V\leq 4000$ and equality is attained iff $x^2=2xh$, i.e. iff $x=2h$, i.e. iff $(x,h)=(20,10)$.
*Phew*.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not correct (volume is $20^2h$ but you have calculated $20h$ {which is not even 300}) but formally you should have used double derivative test, the points at which the derivative is zero are called critical points and double derivative test is used to confirm if a critical point is a point at which the function attains maximum value.

Comment: vanish at maxima? elaborate?

Comment: That's assuming the function to be maximized is differentiable at the critical point. A critical point is a point where the derivative either is zero or does not exist. If it does not exist, you will need to check that the first derivative changes sign there.

Comment: Actually OP's answer is not correct ($300\,cm^3$ is way too small for being the maximum volume, with just a bit of physical intuition) and the meaning of *stationary point* / the statement of Fermat's theorem is not that relevant.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio missed the calculation errors but the OP's method was correct.